# Update data in 'breaking news ticker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-plugins, ejs

**Info:**
I have a site for the local sportsclub that is showing the latest news. I have used an example code called 'Breaking News Ticker' as can be found [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/breaking-news-ticker.html) (example 4). Works great.

**Problem:**
I want to update the news items every x minutes. These headlines are stored in a file and are send by the node-server if I visit ../data/headlines. The initial loading works but any subsequent runs of the code produce a `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).breakingNews is not a function at fillTicker (schemeScripts.js:15:22)`.

**What I've tried:**
Wrapping it all up in a function and then execute that function. Trigger the function with `setInterval`. This produces the error described above.

**Code:**
*scheme.ejs*

```
<div class="bn-breaking-news bn-effect-scroll bn-direction-ltr" id="newsTicker" style="height: 40px; line-height: 38px; border-radius: 2px; border-width: 1px;">
  <div class="bn-label" style="background: #A32638;">NIEUWS</div>
  <div class="bn-news" style="right: 0px;">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="bn-loader-text">Loading news items...</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newsTicker").breakingNews({
      position : 'fixed-bottom',
      source: {
        type:'json',
        url:'../data/headlines', 
        limit:20, 
        showingField:'title',
        linkEnabled: false,
        target:'_blank', 
        seperator: '<span class="bn-seperator" style="background-image:url(./images/logo.png);"></span>',
        errorMsg: 'Json file not loaded. Please check the settings.'
      }
    });
    fillTicker()
    setInterval(fillTicker, msToNextHour())
  })
</script>
```

*schemeScripts.js (containing `fillTicker`)*

```
function fillTicker() {
    console.log("test2")
    $("#newsTicker").breakingNews({
        position : 'fixed-bottom',
        source: {
            type:'json',
            url:'../data/headlines', 
            limit:20, 
            showingField:'title',
            linkEnabled: false,
            target:'_blank', 
            seperator: '<span class="bn-seperator" style="background-image:url(./images/logo.png);"></span>',
            errorMsg: 'Json file not loaded. Please check the settings.'
        }
    });
}
```

I can sort of imagine that this would produce a TypeError but I really struggle/can't get my head around to produce code that does work. Preferably without loading the whole page again. Any help/hints appreciated!

***Edit***
The file `breaking-news-ticker.min.js` is also loaded. Maybe the answer lies withing this file:

```
!function(p) {
    "use strict";
    p.breakingNews = function(e, t) {
        var i = {
            effect: "scroll",
            direction: "ltr",
            height: 40,
            fontSize: "default",
            themeColor: "default",
            background: "default",
            borderWidth: 1,
            radius: 2,
            source: "html",
            rss2jsonApiKey: "",
            play: !0,
            delayTimer: 4e3,
            scrollSpeed: 2,
            stopOnHover: !0,
            position: "auto",
            zIndex: 99999
        }
          , a = this;
        a.settings = {},
        a._element = p(e),
        a._label = a._element.children(".bn-label"),
        a._news = a._element.children(".bn-news"),
        a._ul = a._news.children("ul"),
        a._li = a._ul.children("li"),
        a._controls = a._element.children(".bn-controls"),
        a._prev = a._controls.find(".bn-prev").parent(),
        a._action = a._controls.find(".bn-action").parent(),
        a._next = a._controls.find(".bn-next").parent(),
        a._pause = !1,
        a._controlsIsActive = !0,
        a._totalNews = a._ul.children("li").length,
        a._activeNews = 0,
        a._interval = !1,
        a._frameId = null;
        var o = function() {
            if (0 < a._label.length && ("rtl" == a.settings.direction ? a._news.css({
                right: a._label.outerWidth()
            }) : a._news.css({
                left: a._label.outerWidth()
            })),
            0 < a._controls.length) {
                var e = a._controls.outerWidth();
                "rtl" == a.settings.direction ? a._news.css({
                    left: e
                }) : a._news.css({
                    right: e
                })
            }
            if ("scroll" === a.settings.effect) {
                var t = 0;
                a._li.each(function() {
                    t += p(this).outerWidth()
                }),
                t += 50,
                a._ul.css({
                    width: t
                })
            }
        }
          , s = function() {
            var l = new XMLHttpRequest;
            l.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (4 == l.readyState && 200 == l.status) {
                    var e = JSON.parse(l.responseText)
                      , t = ""
                      , i = "";
                    switch (a.settings.source.showingField) {
                    case "title":
                        i = "title";
                        break;
                    case "description":
                        i = "description";
                        break;
                    case "link":
                        i = "link";
                        break;
                    default:
                        i = "title"
                    }
                    var s = "";
                    void 0 !== a.settings.source.seperator && void 0 !== typeof a.settings.source.seperator && (s = a.settings.source.seperator);
                    for (var n = 0; n < e.items.length; n++)
                        a.settings.source.linkEnabled ? t += '<li><a target="' + a.settings.source.target + '" href="' + e.items[n].link + '">' + s + e.items[n][i] + "</a></li>" : t += "<li><a>" + s + e.items[n][i] + "</a></li>";
                    a._ul.empty().append(t),
                    a._li = a._ul.children("li"),
                    a._totalNews = a._ul.children("li").length,
                    o(),
                    "scroll" != a.settings.effect && d(),
                    a._li.find(".bn-seperator").css({
                        height: a.settings.height - 2 * a.settings.borderWidth
                    }),
                    f()
                }
            }
            ,
            l.open("GET", "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + a.settings.source.url + "&count=" + a.settings.source.limit + "&api_key=" + a.settings.source.rss2jsonApiKey, !0),
            l.send()
        }
          , n = function() {
            p.getJSON(a.settings.source.url, function(e) {
                var t = ""
                  , i = "";
                i = "undefined" === a.settings.source.showingField ? "title" : a.settings.source.showingField;
                var s = "";
                void 0 !== a.settings.source.seperator && void 0 !== typeof a.settings.source.seperator && (s = a.settings.source.seperator);
                for (var n = 0; n < e.length && !(n >= a.settings.source.limit); n++)
                    a.settings.source.linkEnabled ? t += '<li><a target="' + a.settings.source.target + '" href="' + e[n].link + '">' + s + e[n][i] + "</a></li>" : t += "<li><a>" + s + e[n][i] + "</a></li>",
                    "undefined" === e[n][i] && console.log('"' + i + '" does not exist in this json.');
                a._ul.empty().append(t),
                a._li = a._ul.children("li"),
                a._totalNews = a._ul.children("li").length,
                o(),
                "scroll" != a.settings.effect && d(),
                a._li.find(".bn-seperator").css({
                    height: a.settings.height - 2 * a.settings.borderWidth
                }),
                f()
            })
        }
          , l = function() {
            var e = parseFloat(a._ul.css("marginLeft"));
            e -= a.settings.scrollSpeed / 2,
            a._ul.css({
                marginLeft: e
            }),
            e <= -a._ul.find("li:first-child").outerWidth() && (a._ul.find("li:first-child").insertAfter(a._ul.find("li:last-child")),
            a._ul.css({
                marginLeft: 0
            })),
            !1 === a._pause && (a._frameId = requestAnimationFrame(l),
            window.requestAnimationFrame && a._frameId || setTimeout(l, 16))
        }
          , r = function() {
            var e = parseFloat(a._ul.css("marginRight"));
            e -= a.settings.scrollSpeed / 2,
            a._ul.css({
                marginRight: e
            }),
            e <= -a._ul.find("li:first-child").outerWidth() && (a._ul.find("li:first-child").insertAfter(a._ul.find("li:last-child")),
            a._ul.css({
                marginRight: 0
            })),
            !1 === a._pause && (a._frameId = requestAnimationFrame(r)),
            window.requestAnimationFrame && a._frameId || setTimeout(r, 16)
        }
          , c = function() {
            "rtl" === a.settings.direction ? a._ul.stop().animate({
                marginRight: -a._ul.find("li:first-child").outerWidth()
            }, 300, function() {
                a._ul.find("li:first-child").insertAfter(a._ul.find("li:last-child")),
                a._ul.css({
                    marginRight: 0
                }),
                a._controlsIsActive = !0
            }) : a._ul.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: -a._ul.find("li:first-child").outerWidth()
            }, 300, function() {
                a._ul.find("li:first-child").insertAfter(a._ul.find("li:last-child")),
                a._ul.css({
                    marginLeft: 0
                }),
                a._controlsIsActive = !0
            })
        }
          , u = function() {
            "rtl" === a.settings.direction ? (0 <= parseInt(a._ul.css("marginRight"), 10) && (a._ul.css({
                "margin-right": -a._ul.find("li:last-child").outerWidth()
            }),
            a._ul.find("li:last-child").insertBefore(a._ul.find("li:first-child"))),
            a._ul.stop().animate({
                marginRight: 0
            }, 300, function() {
                a._controlsIsActive = !0
            })) : (0 <= parseInt(a._ul.css("marginLeft"), 10) && (a._ul.css({
                "margin-left": -a._ul.find("li:last-child").outerWidth()
            }),
            a._ul.find("li:last-child").insertBefore(a._ul.find("li:first-child"))),
            a._ul.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: 0
            }, 300, function() {
                a._controlsIsActive = !0
            }))
        }
          , d = function() {
            switch (a._controlsIsActive = !0,
            a.settings.effect) {
            case "typography":
                a._ul.find("li").hide(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).width(30).show(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).animate({
                    width: "100%",
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1500);
                break;
            case "fade":
                a._ul.find("li").hide(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).fadeIn();
                break;
            case "slide-down":
                a._totalNews <= 1 ? a._ul.find("li").animate({
                    top: 30,
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).css({
                        top: -30,
                        opacity: 0,
                        display: "block"
                    }),
                    p(this).animate({
                        top: 0,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300)
                }) : (a._ul.find("li:visible").animate({
                    top: 30,
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).hide()
                }),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).css({
                    top: -30,
                    opacity: 0
                }).show(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).animate({
                    top: 0,
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300));
                break;
            case "slide-up":
                a._totalNews <= 1 ? a._ul.find("li").animate({
                    top: -30,
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).css({
                        top: 30,
                        opacity: 0,
                        display: "block"
                    }),
                    p(this).animate({
                        top: 0,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300)
                }) : (a._ul.find("li:visible").animate({
                    top: -30,
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).hide()
                }),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).css({
                    top: 30,
                    opacity: 0
                }).show(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).animate({
                    top: 0,
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300));
                break;
            case "slide-left":
                a._totalNews <= 1 ? a._ul.find("li").animate({
                    left: "50%",
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).css({
                        left: -50,
                        opacity: 0,
                        display: "block"
                    }),
                    p(this).animate({
                        left: 0,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300)
                }) : (a._ul.find("li:visible").animate({
                    left: "50%",
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).hide()
                }),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).css({
                    left: -50,
                    opacity: 0
                }).show(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).animate({
                    left: 0,
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300));
                break;
            case "slide-right":
                a._totalNews <= 1 ? a._ul.find("li").animate({
                    left: "-50%",
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).css({
                        left: "50%",
                        opacity: 0,
                        display: "block"
                    }),
                    p(this).animate({
                        left: 0,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300)
                }) : (a._ul.find("li:visible").animate({
                    left: "-50%",
                    opacity: 0
                }, 300, function() {
                    p(this).hide()
                }),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).css({
                    left: "50%",
                    opacity: 0
                }).show(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).animate({
                    left: 0,
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300));
                break;
            default:
                a._ul.find("li").hide(),
                a._ul.find("li").eq(a._activeNews).show()
            }
        }
          , f = function() {
            if (a._pause = !1,
            a.settings.play)
                switch (a.settings.effect) {
                case "scroll":
                    "rtl" === a.settings.direction ? a._ul.width() > a._news.width() ? r() : a._ul.css({
                        marginRight: 0
                    }) : a._ul.width() > a._news.width() ? l() : a._ul.css({
                        marginLeft: 0
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    a.pause(),
                    a._interval = setInterval(function() {
                        a.next()
                    }, a.settings.delayTimer)
                }
        }
          , _ = function() {
            a._element.width() < 480 ? (a._label.hide(),
            "rtl" == a.settings.direction ? a._news.css({
                right: 0
            }) : a._news.css({
                left: 0
            })) : (a._label.show(),
            "rtl" == a.settings.direction ? a._news.css({
                right: a._label.outerWidth()
            }) : a._news.css({
                left: a._label.outerWidth()
            }))
        };
        a.init = function() {
            if (a.settings = p.extend({}, i, t),
            "fixed-top" === a.settings.position ? a._element.addClass("bn-fixed-top").css({
                "z-index": a.settings.zIndex
            }) : "fixed-bottom" === a.settings.position && a._element.addClass("bn-fixed-bottom").css({
                "z-index": a.settings.zIndex
            }),
            "default" != a.settings.fontSize && a._element.css({
                "font-size": a.settings.fontSize
            }),
            "default" != a.settings.themeColor && (a._element.css({
                "border-color": a.settings.themeColor,
                color: a.settings.themeColor
            }),
            a._label.css({
                background: a.settings.themeColor
            })),
            "default" != a.settings.background && a._element.css({
                background: a.settings.background
            }),
            a._element.css({
                height: a.settings.height,
                "line-height": a.settings.height - 2 * a.settings.borderWidth + "px",
                "border-radius": a.settings.radius,
                "border-width": a.settings.borderWidth
            }),
            a._li.find(".bn-seperator").css({
                height: a.settings.height - 2 * a.settings.borderWidth
            }),
            a._element.addClass("bn-effect-" + a.settings.effect + " bn-direction-" + a.settings.direction),
            o(),
            "object" == typeof a.settings.source)
                switch (a.settings.source.type) {
                case "rss":
                    "rss2json" === a.settings.source.usingApi ? (s(),
                    0 < a.settings.source.refreshTime && setInterval(function() {
                        a._activeNews = 0,
                        a.pause(),
                        a._ul.empty().append('<li style="display:block; padding-left:10px;"><span class="bn-loader-text">......</span></li>'),
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            s()
                        }, 1e3)
                    }, 1e3 * a.settings.source.refreshTime * 60)) : ((l = new XMLHttpRequest).open("GET", "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + encodeURIComponent('select * from rss where url="' + a.settings.source.url + '" limit ' + a.settings.source.limit) + "&format=json", !0),
                    l.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (4 == l.readyState)
                            if (200 == l.status) {
                                var e = JSON.parse(l.responseText)
                                  , t = ""
                                  , i = "";
                                switch (a.settings.source.showingField) {
                                case "title":
                                    i = "title";
                                    break;
                                case "description":
                                    i = "description";
                                    break;
                                case "link":
                                    i = "link";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    i = "title"
                                }
                                var s = "";
                                "undefined" != a.settings.source.seperator && void 0 !== a.settings.source.seperator && (s = a.settings.source.seperator);
                                for (var n = 0; n < e.query.results.item.length; n++)
                                    a.settings.source.linkEnabled ? t += '<li><a target="' + a.settings.source.target + '" href="' + e.query.results.item[n].link + '">' + s + e.query.results.item[n][i] + "</a></li>" : t += "<li><a>" + s + e.query.results.item[n][i] + "</a></li>";
                                a._ul.empty().append(t),
                                a._li = a._ul.children("li"),
                                a._totalNews = a._ul.children("li").length,
                                o(),
                                "scroll" != a.settings.effect && d(),
                                a._li.find(".bn-seperator").css({
                                    height: a.settings.height - 2 * a.settings.borderWidth
                                }),
                                f()
                            } else
                                a._ul.empty().append('<li><span class="bn-loader-text">' + a.settings.source.errorMsg + "</span></li>")
                    }
                    ,
                    l.send(null));
                    break;
                case "json":
                    n(),
                    0 < a.settings.source.refreshTime && setInterval(function() {
                        a._activeNews = 0,
                        a.pause(),
                        a._ul.empty().append('<li style="display:block; padding-left:10px;"><span class="bn-loader-text">......</span></li>'),
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            n()
                        }, 1e3)
                    }, 1e3 * a.settings.source.refreshTime * 60);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Please check your "source" object parameter. Incorrect Value')
                }
            else
                "html" === a.settings.source ? ("scroll" != a.settings.effect && d(),
                f()) : console.log('Please check your "source" parameter. Incorrect Value');
            var l;
            a.settings.play ? a._action.find("span").removeClass("bn-play").addClass("bn-pause") : a._action.find("span").removeClass("bn-pause").addClass("bn-play"),
            a._element.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
                var t = p(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)).parents(".bn-breaking-news")[0];
                p(this)[0] !== t && (!0 === a.settings.stopOnHover ? !0 === a.settings.play && a.play() : !0 === a.settings.play && !0 === a._pause && a.play())
            }),
            a._element.on("mouseenter", function() {
                !0 === a.settings.stopOnHover && a.pause()
            }),
            a._next.on("click", function() {
                a._controlsIsActive && (a._controlsIsActive = !1,
                a.pause(),
                a.next())
            }),
            a._prev.on("click", function() {
                a._controlsIsActive && (a._controlsIsActive = !1,
                a.pause(),
                a.prev())
            }),
            a._action.on("click", function() {
                a._controlsIsActive && (a._action.find("span").hasClass("bn-pause") ? (a._action.find("span").removeClass("bn-pause").addClass("bn-play"),
                a.stop()) : (a.settings.play = !0,
                a._action.find("span").removeClass("bn-play").addClass("bn-pause")))
            }),
            _(),
            p(window).on("resize", function() {
                _(),
                a.pause(),
                a.play()
            })
        }
        ,
        a.pause = function() {
            a._pause = !0,
            clearInterval(a._interval),
            cancelAnimationFrame(a._frameId)
        }
        ,
        a.stop = function() {
            a._pause = !0,
            a.settings.play = !1
        }
        ,
        a.play = function() {
            f()
        }
        ,
        a.next = function() {
            !function() {
                switch (a.settings.effect) {
                case "scroll":
                    c();
                    break;
                default:
                    a._activeNews++,
                    a._activeNews >= a._totalNews && (a._activeNews = 0),
                    d()
                }
            }()
        }
        ,
        a.prev = function() {
            !function() {
                switch (a.settings.effect) {
                case "scroll":
                    u();
                    break;
                default:
                    a._activeNews--,
                    a._activeNews < 0 && (a._activeNews = a._totalNews - 1),
                    d()
                }
            }()
        }
        ,
        a.init()
    }
    ,
    p.fn.breakingNews = function(t) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (null == p(this).data("breakingNews")) {
                var e = new p.breakingNews(this,t);
                p(this).data("breakingNews", e)
            }
        })
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: where the schemeScripts.js is imported? make sure it is loaded after the breaking-news-ticker.

Comment: `schemeScripts.js` is imported at the top of the file `scheme.ejs`. However, it is called after the loading of the breaking-news-ticker. And this part works ok. It loads correctly. It just does not want to reload with the `setInterval` and show changes

Comment: I've added jquery tags. Also, as it seems the plugin is not distributed anymore, you might remove it after the issue is resolved

Comment: Maybe there is correlation between it not working and the removal of the plugin... ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the plugin is deleted, so make sure it's not being manipulated elsewhere.

To achieve reload, the plugin needs to be reset, along with all data and listeners etc., so a proper way would be to extend the plugin with reset methods.

A quick and dirty way to achieve that would be to replace ticker container in the interval function.

```
// html
let newsTickerHTML;

$(document).ready(function () {

// store ticker clean html to replace later
newsTickerHTML = $('#newsTicker').parent().html();
```

and later:

```
function fillTicker() {

    // reset
    $('#newsTicker').parent().html(newsTickerHTML);
```

code:

```
let newsTickerHTML;

  $(document).ready(function () {

    // store ticker clean html to replace later
    newsTickerHTML = $('#newsTicker').parent().html();


    $("#newsTicker").breakingNews({
      position : 'fixed-bottom',
      source: {
        type:'json',
        url:'../data/headlines', 
        limit:20, 
        showingField:'title',
        linkEnabled: false,
        target:'_blank', 
        seperator: '<span class="bn-seperator" style="background-image:url(./images/logo.png);"></span>',
        errorMsg: 'Json file not loaded. Please check the settings.'
      }
    });
    fillTicker()
    setInterval(fillTicker, msToNextHour())
  });


function fillTicker() {

    // reset
    $('#newsTicker').parent().html(newsTickerHTML);

    console.log("test2")
    $("#newsTicker").breakingNews({
        position : 'fixed-bottom',
        source: {
            type:'json',
            url:'../data/headlines', 
            limit:20, 
            showingField:'title',
            linkEnabled: false,
            target:'_blank', 
            seperator: '<span class="bn-seperator" style="background-image:url(./images/logo.png);"></span>',
            errorMsg: 'Json file not loaded. Please check the settings.'
        }
    });
}
```

**edit**

Also wrap plugin HTML code into a parent container:

```
<div>
    <div class="bn-breaking-news bn-effect-scroll bn-direction-ltr" id="newsTicker" style="height: 40px; line-height: 38px; border-radius: 2px; border-width: 1px;">
      <div class="bn-label" style="background: #A32638;">NIEUWS</div>
      <div class="bn-news" style="right: 0px;">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span class="bn-loader-text">Loading news items...</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**edit 2**

Try merging code so that it runs in the template completely, and only depends on jQuery:

```
<div>
    <div class="bn-breaking-news bn-effect-scroll bn-direction-ltr" id="newsTicker" style="height: 40px; line-height: 38px; border-radius: 2px; border-width: 1px;">
        <div class="bn-label" style="background: #A32638;">NIEUWS</div>
        <div class="bn-news" style="right: 0px;">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="bn-loader-text">Loading news items...</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// html
let newsTickerHTML;

$(document).ready(function() {

    // store ticker clean html to replace later
    newsTickerHTML = $('#newsTicker').parent().html();

    function fillTicker() {

        console.log("test2")

        // reset
        $('#newsTicker').parent().html(newsTickerHTML);


        $("#newsTicker").breakingNews({
            position: 'fixed-bottom',
            source: {
                type: 'json',
                url: '../data/headlines',
                limit: 20,
                showingField: 'title',
                linkEnabled: false,
                target: '_blank',
                seperator: '<span class="bn-seperator" style="background-image:url(./images/logo.png);"></span>',
                errorMsg: 'Json file not loaded. Please check the settings.'
            }
        });
    }

    fillTicker()
    setInterval(fillTicker, msToNextHour())
});
</script>
```

Comment: The first pass of the Javascript, including the `fillTicker()` works, any subsequent passes (via `setInterval`) do fail and produce the `schemeScripts.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).breakingNews is not a function at fillTicker (schemeScripts.js:17:22)`-error

Comment: along with the code from my answer, try placing plugin HTML code into a parent div, see the updated code

Comment: I did just that because all the Javascript was otherwise loading again as well, not just the HTML. This still produces the error ;(

Comment: can't reproduce.. try merging the code so that it completely runs from the template, try code under __edit 2__ if that fails, include code where you include jquery, ticker, ejs, schemeScripts, I guess it's either some scoping issue, or some HTML bug which causes the plugin to break somehow, or maybe cache, it's hard to tell..

Comment: I really appreciate your help @traynor. But this also seems not to be working. I have now amended my code to a different approach, being a `ticker.ejs` template. See my own 'answer'.
Or should I update my question? Don't know what the Stack-standerd is in this sort of change...

Comment: try creating a single route, where you render only the template which contains code from edit 2

Comment: That works! But how to implement this further? Maybe incorporate this in my secondary approach?

Comment: great. well, there's apparently some conflict with the code you have in the inital template.. so, it's now matter of debugging. try adding stuff from the initial template, piece by piece, and see when it breaks.. maybe it's invalid HTML, maybe is some other code you have which creates some conflict.. (I'd forget about your approach, because it overloads your server, and still requires extra code..)

Comment: In a separate file it runs great. Including code in `scheme.ejs` does not work. Loading a partial with the 'separate' code works well but somehow I then get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'newsTickerHTML' has already been declared` error at this line: `$('#newsTicker').parent().html(newsTickerHTML);`. I can live with that for now but if you have a clue, please pass me a hint ^_^
FYI, despite the error, it now does update and keeps running :)

Comment: and if you move `let newsTickerHTML` inside `$(document).ready(function() {...`? also, maybe using some older jquery version, but that's just wild guessing now..